# Unable to abstract out the resolve function in a GraphQL query definition

Tags: graphql

I have a GraphQL query field stored in a separate **queries/book.js** file:

```
const {
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLSchema,
  GraphQLID,
  GraphQLInt,
  GraphQLList,
  GraphQLNonNull,
} = require('graphql');
const Book = require('../../../models/book');
const Author = require('../../../models/author');
const {BookType, AuthorType} = require('../types');

module.exports = {
  type: BookType,
  args: { id: { type: GraphQLID } },
  resolve: (parent, args) => {
    // code to get data from db
    return Book.findById(args.id);
  },
};
```

I'm trying to take the resolve function out of the query object for better modularity:

```
const {
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLSchema,
  GraphQLID,
  GraphQLInt,
  GraphQLList,
  GraphQLNonNull,
} = require('graphql');
const Book = require('../../../models/book');
const Author = require('../../../models/author');
const {BookType, AuthorType} = require('../types');

const resolveAuthor = (parent, args) => {
  // code to get data from db
  return Book.findById(args.id);
};

module.exports = {
  type: BookType,
  args: { id: { type: GraphQLID } },
  resolve: resolveAuthor(parent, args)
};
```

However, doing this throws a reference error on the penultimate line saying "parent" is not defined. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say

```
module.exports = { resolve: resolveAuthor(parent, args) };
```

that syntax actually tries to call the resolve function and export its return value.  You don't want to do that here (and can't, because you don't know the parent object or per-call arguments); you can just pass the function back as is

```
module.exports = { resolve: resolveAuthor };
```